# .FindNext in a loop doesnt' work

Tags: excel, vba, loops, find, set

I am using this loop to look for values. .Find works but findNext does not, ommiting many values. Here I drop my code, do you have any advice? thank you very much!!

```
For Each ws In SourceWb.Worksheets
    If IsNumeric(Left(ws.Name, 3)) Then
        Set gCell = ws.Columns(6).Find(what:=numdoc, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
        If Not gCell Is Nothing And IsNumeric(Left(gCell.Parent.Name, 3)) Then

            firstAddress = gCell.Address

            Do
                repetidos = repetidos + 1
                finalcell = gCell.Address
                'merged cells code here not displayed
                oldaddress = gCell.Address
                '>Having trouble here> **
                Set gCell = ws.Columns(6).FindNext(after:=gCell)
                '**


            Loop Until gCell.Address = oldaddress
        End If
    End If
Next ws
```

Comment: Does that compile for you? I get a `Next without For` compile error.

Comment: Yes it does, I might have errased a end if when making the post, try deleting this code sentence: If firstAddress <> oldaddress Then

Comment: How have you declared the variables? I don't think that's the problem but I have difficulty trying to replicate your problem. Have you looked at the logic in your `Do...Loop`?

Comment: Ok I found what was going on, I did the .find over a determined range and the other values I was looking for where out this range, that's why was not finding them. So the loop and findnext works, but the correct way to arrange this to make it faster (I think) would be to put the .find before the sheet for and extract the values that I need. Thank you very much for your time :)

Comment: Thanks. Try to be a bit more careful with indentation in If and loop structures when asking SO questions - you will get more response that way. I only commented initially because the correct indentation suggested you just needad a pointer in the right direction. **Good luck and enjoy SO**

Comment: So bad I found that it was working because I wrote an "On error resume next" statement. I deleted this statement and now is giving me this error "91, variable object or with not established". What can I do???

Comment: I guess it's about declaring the object (gcell) or a with (including ws?) but I am lost. thxx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was the best I could derive from your clues:

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim SourceWB As Workbook
Dim numdoc As Long
Dim gCell As Range
Dim firstAddress As String
Dim oldaddress As String
Dim finalcell As String
Dim repetidos As Long

Set SourceWB = ThisWorkbook 'added for clarity and safety
numdoc = 456
    For Each WS In SourceWB.Worksheets
        If IsNumeric(Left(WS.Name, 3)) Then 'OK I had to save it as "123 A"
            Set gCell = WS.Columns(6).Find(what:=numdoc, _
                LookIn:=xlValues, _
                lookat:=xlWhole, _
                SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                MatchCase:=False, _
                searchformat:=False)
            If Not gCell Is Nothing And IsNumeric(Left(gCell.Parent.Name, 3)) Then
                firstAddress = gCell.Address
                Set gCell = WS.Columns(6).FindNext(after:=gCell)
                Do
                    repetidos = repetidos + 1
                    finalcell = gCell.Address
                    'merged cells code here not displayed
                    oldaddress = gCell.Address
                Loop Until gCell.Address = oldaddress
            End If
        End If
    Next WS
End Sub
```

Not sure if it answers the question but, it does demonstrate indentation.

There's probably room for a `With...End With` in there but I'm too tired to look for it.

Comment: It might be that (with) I'll look for it and try to place it before for each ws in sourcewb.worksheets. thank you very much though

Comment: Try it as high in your structure as you can. Don't forget the dots `.`

Comment: A tick would be nice :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 This seems to work at this point.

 For Each WS In SourceWB.Worksheets
    With ws.Range("F:F")
    If IsNumeric(Left(WS.Name, 3)) Then 'OK I had to save it as "123 A"
        Set gCell = .Find(what:=numdoc, _
            LookIn:=xlValues, _
            lookat:=xlWhole, _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            MatchCase:=False, _
            searchformat:=False)
        If Not gCell Is Nothing And IsNumeric(Left(gCell.Parent.Name, 3)) Then
            firstAddress = gCell.Address
            Set gCell = .FindNext(after:=gCell)
            Do


                'merged cells code here not displayed

            Loop While Not gCell Is Nothing And gCell.Address <> firstAddress
        End If
    End If
 end with
Next WS
```